# Creating dynamic menus with GTKMM and UIManager

Tags: dynamic, menu, gtkmm, uimanager

I have a problem: I can create menus with UIManager class in GTKMM, but I don't know how to modify(edit or remove items) at run-time. I found some examples gnome developer site, but none of them solved my problem. I found [this](http://gtk.10911.n7.nabble.com/UIManager-and-dynamic-menus-td38510.html) site, but it doesn't helped for me because I don't have the complete source code to study. It would be fine if somebody could post a complete source code, or mention other solution. I'm using C++(gcc) and Ubuntu 13.10.

PS: Sorry for my grammar.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest not trying to use UIManger for dynamic menus and only use UIManager for static menus. If you want to create a dynamic menus here is one way to do it:

```
#include <gtkmm.h>

class MainWindow : public Gtk::Window
{
public:
    MainWindow();
    virtual ~MainWindow();
    void newTab();

protected:
    void buttonAddClicked();
    void buttonDeleteClicked();

    Gtk::Box box_;
    Gtk::MenuItem* item;
    Gtk::Menu* submenu1;
    Gtk::MenuItem* subitem1;
    Gtk::MenuItem* item2;
    Gtk::Menu* submenu2;
    Gtk::MenuItem* subitem2;
    Gtk::ButtonBox buttonbox_;
    Gtk::Button button_delete_;
    Gtk::Button button_add_;
};

MainWindow::MainWindow()
{
    this->set_title("Menu Test");
    this->set_default_size(300, 400);
    box_.set_orientation(Gtk::ORIENTATION_VERTICAL);
    this->add(box_);

    item = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::MenuItem("test"));
    submenu1 = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::Menu);
    subitem1 = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::MenuItem("sub Item"));
    submenu1->append(*subitem1);
    item->set_submenu(*submenu1);
    item2 = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::MenuItem("test2"));
    submenu2 = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::Menu);
    subitem2 = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::MenuItem("sub item 2"));
    submenu2->append(*subitem2);
    item2->set_submenu(*submenu2);
    Gtk::MenuBar* menubar = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::MenuBar);
    //nmenu->append(*item);
    menubar->append(*item);
    menubar->append(*item2);
    box_.add(*menubar);

    button_delete_.set_label("Delete");
    button_add_.set_label("Add");
    box_.add(buttonbox_);
    buttonbox_.add(button_delete_);
    buttonbox_.add(button_add_);

    button_delete_.signal_clicked().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &MainWindow::buttonDeleteClicked));
    button_add_.signal_clicked().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &MainWindow::buttonAddClicked));

    this->show_all_children();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{

}

void MainWindow::buttonAddClicked()
{
    Gtk::MenuItem* newitem = Gtk::manage(new Gtk::MenuItem("new Item"));
    submenu1->append(*newitem);
    newitem->show_all();
}

void MainWindow::buttonDeleteClicked()
{
    subitem2->hide();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{   
    Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Application> app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "menu.example");

    MainWindow mw;

    app->run(mw);

    return 0;
}
```

As you see it is not that difficult to create a regular menu with Gtkmm. It's almost the same as using UIManager. If this example does not work for you, what you can try is using GtkBuiler instead of UIManager. GtkBuilder is easier to use and is more friendly.